# Generate resource-env-ref entries in maven-ear-plugin generated application.xml

Tags: maven, ear, maven-ear-plugin, application.xml

so the need is to add resource-env-ref entries in a maven project who's application.xml is generated by maven-ear-plugin.

Checked with the source of the plugin and there's nothing even remotely close to resource-env-ref. And it's difficult to believe nobody had this need until now.

The only alternative I see, for the moment, is to hand written the application.xml and use the resource plugin to keep the versions in change.

Comment: Do you use sar/rar modules ? BTW: Have you made a [feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MEAR/) if it does not exist?

Comment: No, I don't use. It's a "normal" ear consisting of some jar entries, one ejb module, and one war. And changing it into something else (like a war with ejb lite) is not an option at the moment.

Comment: I just created a feature request here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MEAR-247 
Please vote for it in Jira if you're interested.